# Module runs on IDE but won't compile to EXE

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

My python 3.6 code runs perfectly on the IDLE and PyCharm IDE but when I try to compile to exe with pyinstaller errors occur and the exe will not run.

I import several external python modules to get the things done.

Am I missing something?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import time

import PyPDF2
import easygui
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from selenium import webdriver

# User to input file
userpath = easygui.fileopenbox()
print('Loading request file:')
print(userpath)
print('\n')

# Read excel file document with 4 columns: Document, Batch Number, Prints, Duplex
documentlist = pd.read_excel(userpath, usecols='A,B,C,D')
df = pd.DataFrame(documentlist)

#  Format column Document numbers to 3 digits
df['Document'] = df['Document'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>3}'.format(x))
#  Deactivate Pandas silly message
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

#  Convert numeric values to string type FAR-BR-02.XXX
value = 'FAR'
df['Document'] = df['Document'].astype(str)

list = df['Document']

for x in range(len(list)):
    if value not in list[x]:
        list[x] = 'FAR-BR-02.' + str(list[x])
    else:
        continue

df['Document'] = list
print(df)

downloadlist = np.unique(list)

print('\n')
print('Your request contains', len(documentlist['Document']), 'documents, of which, ')
print(len(downloadlist), ' are unique (no repeats) to be retrieved from Proquis: ')
print('\n')
print(downloadlist)
print('\n')

# Prep a temp folder for downloads
# Check if the temp folder exists otherwise, create it
temppath = 'C:/pdfstampertemp/'
if not os.path.exists(temppath):
    os.makedirs(temppath)
# Check temp folder is empty otherwise, clean it
if os.listdir(temppath) != []:
    fileList = os.listdir(temppath)
    for fileName in fileList:
        os.remove(temppath + fileName)

# Download files from SSL Proquis using Chromedriver

print('Downloading files from Proquis. Authenticate if required.')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
preferences = {"download.default_directory": 'C:\pdfstampertemp',
               "directory_upgrade": True,
               "download.prompt_for_download": False,
               "safebrowsing.enabled": True}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
                          executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://proquis.btgplc.com/viewdocument.aspx?DOCNO='
urllist = downloadlist
for x in range(len(downloadlist)):
    urllist[x] = url + str(downloadlist[x])
    driver.get(urllist[x])

print('Download completed!')
print ('\n')
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()


# Decrypt downloaded PDFs
# Copy qpdf to temp directory
print('Preparing PDFs ...')
qpdffiles = ['qpdf.exe','qpdf21.dll','libwinpthread-1.dll','libstdc++-6.dll','libiconv2.dll','libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll']

for x in range(len(qpdffiles)):
    shutil.copy2(qpdffiles[x], 'c://pdfstampertemp/' + qpdffiles[x])

# Change cwd to decrypt
installdir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('c://pdfstampertemp/')

# Call qpdf to decrypt pdfs
workinglist = np.unique(list)
downloadlist = np.unique(list)
for x in range(len(downloadlist)):
    downloadlist[x] = downloadlist[x] + '.PDF'
    workinglist[x] = 'D' + downloadlist[x]
    subprocess.run(["qpdf.exe", "--decrypt", downloadlist[x], workinglist[x]])
print('Ready! Stamping now. This may take some time according with the PDF size. Please wait...')
print('\n')

# Set the cwd back to the install directory
os.chdir(installdir)

# Order the file list by batch number
df = df.sort_values('BatchNo')

# Prep: declare variables and create first stamp headers
inputpdf = 'D' + df['Document'] + '.PDF'
outputpdf = 'SD' + df['Document'] + '.PDF'
batchno = df['BatchNo']
copies = df['Copies']
duplex = df['Single/Double']
stamp = ['StampP.pdf', 'StampL.pdf']
# Bach number position in page Portrait and Landscape (x,y)
xp = 400
yp = 780
xl = 640
yl = 530


# Create inital stapms for first entry
batch = str(batchno[1])


# Portrait: create a new PDF with Reportlab, insert the text in set location with specified font
packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
can.setFont('Times-Bold', 16)
can.drawString(xp, yp, batch)
can.save()

# move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read the existing PDF
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("BlankStampP.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = open("StampP.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

# Landscape: create a new PDF with Reportlab, insert the text in set location with specified font
packet = io.BytesIO()
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
can.setFont('Times-Bold', 16)
can.drawString(xl, yl, batch)
can.save()

# move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
# read the existing PDF
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("BlankStampL.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
# add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
# finally, write "output" to a real file
outputStream = open("StampL.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

# Watermark the first PDF

input = temppath + inputpdf[0]
inputfile = open(input, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(inputfile)

pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    inputfilePage = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
    page = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum).mediaBox
    if (page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x()) > (page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y()):
        stamp ='StampL.pdf'
    else:
        stamp = 'StampP.pdf'
    pdfWatermarkReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(stamp, 'rb'))
    inputfilePage.mergePage(pdfWatermarkReader.getPage(0))
    pdfWriter.addPage(inputfilePage)
resultPdfFile = open(str(temppath + '0' + outputpdf[0]), 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdfFile)
inputfile.close()
resultPdfFile.close()

# Rest of the files - create new stamp only if needed

for i in range(1,len(inputpdf)):
        if batchno[i] != batchno[i-1]:
            # Portrait: create a new PDF with Reportlab, insert the text in set location with specified font
            packet = io.BytesIO()
            can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
            can.setFont('Times-Bold', 16)
            can.drawString(xp, yp, str(batchno[i]))
            can.save()

            # move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
            packet.seek(0)
            new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
            # read the existing PDF
            existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("BlankStampP.pdf", "rb"))
            output = PdfFileWriter()
            # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
            page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
            page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
            output.addPage(page)
            # finally, write "output" to a real file
            outputStream = open("StampP.pdf", "wb")
            output.write(outputStream)
            outputStream.close()

            # Landscape: create a new PDF with Reportlab, insert the text in set location with specified font
            packet = io.BytesIO()
            can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=A4)
            can.setFont('Times-Bold', 16)
            can.drawString(xl, yl, str(batchno[i]))
            can.save()

            # move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
            packet.seek(0)
            new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
            # read the existing PDF
            existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("BlankStampL.pdf", "rb"))
            output = PdfFileWriter()
            # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
            page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
            page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
            output.addPage(page)
            # finally, write "output" to a real file
            outputStream = open("StampL.pdf", "wb")
            output.write(outputStream)
            outputStream.close()

        # Stamp them
        input = temppath + inputpdf[i]
        inputfile = open(input, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(inputfile)

        pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            inputfilePage = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
            page = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum).mediaBox
            if (page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x()) > (page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y()):
                stamp = 'StampL.pdf'
            else:
                stamp = 'StampP.pdf'
            pdfWatermarkReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(stamp, 'rb'))
            inputfilePage.mergePage(pdfWatermarkReader.getPage(0))
            pdfWriter.addPage(inputfilePage)
        resultPdfFile = open(str(temppath + str(i) + outputpdf[i]), 'wb')
        pdfWriter.write(resultPdfFile)
        inputfile.close()
        resultPdfFile.close()
print("Stamping has completed.")
print('Script terminated. Have a nice day!')
```

I guess I need to define this is the main module somehow and the others are imports.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the system path for Python 3.7 not incorrectly set up in Windows 10.

All done now, I was able to create an EXE with pyinstaller (although multiple warnings and errors were shown).

The EXE runs exactly like the py in Python 3.7.

Comment: Please flag your question as `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced`.